# Formatting Number in javascript using decimal

Tags: javascript, format

I have following types of values in a, b,c,d.

```
a= 12345678
b= 12345678.098
c=12345678.1
d=12345678.11
```

I need to format  like,

```
a = 12,345,678.000
b=  12,345,678.098
c=12,345,678.100
d=12,345,678.110
```

I already tried tolocaleString() and toFixed(3) method. But I'm not able to works together of both method.

need your suggestion on this.

Comment: How can I achieve without using minimumFractionDigits? maximumFractionDigits?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Number in javascript without using minimumFractionDigits, maximumFractionDigits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403486/formatting-number-in-javascript-without-using-minimumfractiondigits-maximumfrac)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var num = 123456789;
console.log(num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 3, maximumFractionDigits: 3}));
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

`undefined` will use user's locale, you might want to specify a custom one.

---

Updated answer

```js
var number = 12345678;
console.log(parseInt(number*1000).toLocaleString("en-US").replace(/\,([^\,]*)$/,"."+'$1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat),

```
var number = 12345678.098;
alert(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
```

Here's a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kz2ksyza/)**

Comment: You can add the `options` parameter to get the decimal behaviour (e.g. `12345678` -> `'12345678.00'`): `new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 3, maximumFractionDigits: 3 }).format(number)`, or provide this to `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` as @BrahmaDev has in his answer

Comment: What is your browser name & version?

Comment: @BrahmaDev Check your [`Browser Compatibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Comment: @CraigAyre the output is dependent on browser version

Comment: I'm getting Intl undefined error while running in IE