# Formatting Number in javascript without using minimumFractionDigits, maximumFractionDigits

Tags: javascript, format

I have following types of values in `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

```
a= 12345678
b= 12345678.098
c=12345678.1
d=12345678.11
```

I need to format like,

```
a = 12,345,678.000
b=  12,345,678.098
c=12,345,678.100
d=12,345,678.110
```

I already tried `tolocaleString()` and `toFixed(3)` method. But I'm not able to works together of both method.

need your suggestion on this.

Comment: You don't need any formatted numbers, numbers can't be formatted in JS. If you need "formatted numbers", the only chance is to convert the numbers to strings, and format those strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401854/formatting-number-in-javascript-using-decimal/46401920#46401920

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```js
var a = 12345678;
var b = 12345678.098;
var c = 12345678.1;
var d = 12345678.11;

String.prototype.format = function() {
  return this.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
};

function formatNumber(input) {
  return parseFloat(input).toFixed(3).toString().format();
}

console.log(formatNumber(a));
console.log(formatNumber(b));
console.log(formatNumber(c));
console.log(formatNumber(d));
```